# How to find duplicate entries but first group by a column and then count and show it

Tags: mysql

Hello I cannot solve this. I have a table with user entries and ips. My goal is to find the user 1 and user 2 with same ip.

```
user_id    | IP
1003       | 1.1.1.1
1003       | 1.1.1.1
1003       | 2.2.2.2
1004       | 1.1.1.1
1004       | 3.3.3.3      
1005       | 4.4.4.4
1005       | 5.5.5.5
```

What I want is this

```
user_id    | same_ip_count
1003       | 2
1004       | 2
```

Here you see 1003 and 1004 showing 2 because both had at least one time same ip.

What I only could get is to show me ALL IPS which had multiple user.

```
SELECT 
    ip, COUNT(distinct user_id) as used_by_user_count 
FROM 
    user_entry 
WHERE 
    ip != ''
GROUP BY 
    ip
HAVING 
    used_by_user_count > 1
```

And this is the result

```
ip         | used_by_user_count
1.1.1.1    | 2
```

But I couldn't make it work to get user_id instead of ips. Then I tried subqueries (little bit with guesses) but I failed. I hope you can help me.

EDIT: I made quick sqlfiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f8f04/4

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

I would do a self-join from each row to any other row(s) that have the same ip but a different user. By using an inner join, this naturally finds only cases where there are more than one user. So add one to count the first user `a`.

```
select a.user_id, count(distinct b.user_id)+1 as count 
from user_entry as a 
join user_entry as b on a.ip = b.ip and a.user_id <> b.user_id 
group by a.user_id;

+---------+-------+
| user_id | count |
+---------+-------+
|    1002 |     2 |
|    1001 |     2 |
+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `count(distinct b.user_id)`?

Comment: Depends on whether you want to count multiple uses of the same ip by the same user. I guess the OP did show an example of that in the post above (but not in the SQLFiddle), so yes, `COUNT(distinct b.user_id)` is appropriate. Fixed.

Comment: Yea this is exactly what I want. However on the fiddle I have no problem. If I do this on my mysql the CPU has 100% usage and cannot see the result. I limited to one day with 4000 entries. Still no luck :/

Comment: @MaZy, what indexes have you defined for the table? When asking SQL questions, it's always a good idea to run `SHOW CREATE TABLE user_entry` (or any other table referenced in your query), and include the result with your question.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is not important, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to list all users sharing the same IP:

```
SELECT 
    ip,
    COUNT(distinct user_id) as used_by_user_count,
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct user_id) as user_ids
FROM user_entry 
WHERE ip != ''
GROUP BY ip
HAVING used_by_user_count > 1;
```

Result would be:

```
|      ip | used_by_user_count |  user_ids |
|---------|--------------------|-----------|
| 1.1.1.1 |                  2 | 1003,1004 |
```

Answer (score 0):

for get the user with more that one ip  you could use count(distinct ip)

```
  select user_id, count(distinct ip)
  from user_entry
  group by user_id
  having count(distinct ip) > 1
```

and 
for get the user with the same ip  you can use

```
select a.ip, a.user_id 
   from user_entry a 
   inner join (
      select ip, count(distinct user_id)
      from user_entry
      group by ip
      having count(distinct user_id) > 1
) t on t.ip  = a.ip
```

Comment: But that is no correct. Your solution just counts ips that are used by one user_id.  But the goal is to find same ip which was used by user1 and user2 and show these user and count the same ip.

Comment: answer  updated ... hope is what you are looking for

Comment: I get " ambiguous" error I think we need to change to "a.ip..." But even with this I get 0 results. I setup sqlfiddle for more precision.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fff07/4